# owl carousel add dynamically another item with vue js

Tags: vue.js, owl-carousel

In my vue component i have a data array that contain a list of image;
so i render these image with v-for

```
<div class="body-details-img-gall GalleryImgSlide" id="slideup">
    <img :data-hash="'slide-' + item.id" :src="asset + 'image/message/chat/' + id + '/' + item.filename" class="d-block w-100" alt="" v-for="(item, i) in (pictures)" :key="'slideup-' + item.id">
</div>
```

so in my mounted i initialise [the owl carousel](https://github.com/s950329/vue-owl-carousel#readme)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".GalleryImgSlide").owlCarousel(
       {
           items:1,
           smartSpeed:450,
           nav: true,
           mouseDrag: false,
           URLhashListener:true,
           startPosition: 'URLHash',
       }
    );
 }.bind(this))
```

my carousel work fine; now i want to push another picture inside the data pictures; but it's not considered by the actual carousel;

Is there a way to re-render the carousel after pushing data or is it possible to add the item dynamically on the caroussel?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+owl-carousel) are my 2 related answers concerning owlcarousel (and how to work with an alternative carousel). TLDR: don't use owlcarousel because it's old, deprecated and not adapted for this. Also, please do not use jQuery + querySelectors too.

Comment: Use this package for VUE https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel

Comment: No update since November 2018, quite heavy, relies on jQuery. I'd pass on this one too tbh.